# draw realistic clouds with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've drawn the following image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{sunbody/.style={line width=1pt,draw=orange,fill=yellow,circle,minimum size=5cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw ground
\fill[brown] (-20,0) -- (-5,10) -- (15,10) -- (8,0) -- cycle;
% draw sun
\draw (13,16) node[sunbody] {};
% draw cloud
\node[cloud, cloud puffs = 10, draw, minimum width = 7cm, minimum height = 4cm, fill = gray!10] at (8,15){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

where the brown area is the earth surface. I would like to try and make this more realistic. I am quite happy with most of the drawing, apart from the cloud. Can anyone suggest a method for making the cloud look more realistic? Its kind of hard to put this into words but I would like it to cover a greater portion of the sky similar to what clouds actually look like in reality, with gaps and such. Hope this makes sense. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Draw it by hand in Inkscape and export the path as a TikZ code. Programming free hand vector graphics is super annoying and much easier with mouse-clicking.

Comment: In this view, it is difficult to draw it even by hand.

Comment: @percusse Using inkscape, how would someone draw the clouds to look cover the x and y directions, if that makes sense?

Comment: you can put the path in a scope and scale it as you wish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a possible realisation of a more realistic cloud (and sun and ground).

[image]

I have used the shadows library, see *Section 66. Shadows* in the TikZ & PGF manual (version 3.0.0). For the clouds I have only drawn circles that overlap each other in a quite regular grid (see the code below the comment `% cloud`). If you want something else, you can draw (not entirely) overlapping shapes in a more irregular way to achieve a more natural look.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, shadows}

\colorlet{groundcolor}{Black!5!Tan}
\colorlet{darkgroundcolor}{groundcolor!75!Black}
\colorlet{suncolor}{Gold!50!Yellow}
\colorlet{lightsuncolor}{White!5!Gold!35!Yellow}
\colorlet{cloudcolor}{LightGrey!50!Lavender}

\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{distorted}=[xslant=1.125,%
        yscale=0.4]

    % ground
    \filldraw[groundcolor, distorted] (0, 0) rectangle (10, 10);
    \foreach \x in {0.1, 0.2, ..., 9.9} {
        \draw[darkgroundcolor,%
            very thick,%
            decoration={random steps,%
                segment length=3pt,%
                amplitude=0.5pt},%
            decorate,%
            distorted] (\x, 0.075) -- (\x, 9.925);
    }

    % complex sun
    \begin{scope}[xshift=13cm, yshift=7cm]
    \foreach \x in {0, 30, ..., 350} {
        \filldraw[suncolor,%
            circular glow={fill=suncolor},%
            rotate=\x] (-0.75, 0) parabola (0, 1.35) parabola[bend at end] (0.75, 0) -- cycle;
    }
    \filldraw[lightsuncolor,%
        circular glow={fill=lightsuncolor}] (0, 0) circle[radius=0.75];
    \end{scope}

    % simple sun
    %\filldraw[suncolor,
    %   circular glow={fill=suncolor}] (13, 7) circle[radius=1];

    % cloud
    \foreach \x / \y in {10 / 6, 10.5 / 6.5, 11.5 / 6.5, 12 / 6, 11 / 5.75} {
        \filldraw[cloudcolor,%
            circular glow={fill=cloudcolor}] (\x, \y) circle [radius=0.75];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

A teensy bit kludgy, and the randomness doesn't always give brilliant results, but anyway...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (sun) at (4,3);
\foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
   \shade [top color=yellow, bottom color=orange, shift=(sun)] 
     (0,0) -- (\i:4) arc(\i:\i+15:4) -- cycle;
\shade [top color=yellow, bottom color=orange] (sun) circle [radius=2];

\foreach \c in {0,1,2,3,4}{
  \shade [shift={(\c*2+rand*2-6,{mod(\c,2)+rnd*3-1})}, 
  top color=cyan, bottom color=blue!50] 
  (3,0) \foreach \i [evaluate={\k=3-\c*.5; \j=rnd*10; \xr=3+\k/5+rnd/2; \yr=\k+rnd;}] in {1,...,9}{
  to [bend right, out=300+\j, in=240-\j] ({\i*20+(rnd*5*\i<9)}:\xr\space and \yr)
};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image: realiztic cloud]

Of course, the work is in filling the background with transparent pixels.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{sunbody/.style={line width=1pt,draw=orange,fill=yellow,circle,minimum size=5cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw ground
\fill[brown] (-20,0) -- (-5,10) -- (15,10) -- (8,0) -- cycle;
% draw sun
\draw (13,16) node[sunbody] {};
% draw cloud
\node[scale=0.5] at (8,15){\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external=cloud}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The clouds are spectacular.