# Communication Diagram in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to find a way to generate the following diagram using TikZ:

[image: Example Diagram]

I know how to generate it minus the adornments such as the cloud, and icons for the server and client (using a simple node like a circle etc.), but I haven't been able to find any library of shapes that would allow me to replicate this. As a stop-gap I can use OmniGraffle on the Mac to generate a scaleable PDF, but if I can use TikZ to do this I'd prefer to.

Comment: There is a cloud node shape in the `shapes.symbols` library. See chapter 72.4 in the TikZ manual. The simplest method for the server and client would be `\includegraphics` I guess.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194211/draw-realistic-clouds-with-tikz